# How do I add properties to subdocument array in aggregation/make $map like $addFields?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
> db.things.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : [ { "x" : 2, "y" : 1 }, { "x" : 0, "y" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "a" : [ { "x" : 2, "y" : 5, "abitraryPropertyWhichShouldBeKept" : true } ] }
```

I could like to add a calculated property, say `magnitude`, to each subdocument at `a`. I don’t want to have to specify `x` and `y` manually, and there might be other properties I need to keep. My attempt so far (where I have to manually specify `x` and `y` which I shouldn’t have to do):

```
db.things.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
     a: {
       $map: {
         input: '$a',
         as: 'item',
         'in': {
           x: '$$item.x',
           y: '$$item.y',
           magnitude: {
             $sqrt: {
               $add: [
                 { $pow: ['$$item.x', 2], },
                 { $pow: ['$$item.y', 2] }],
               },
             },
           },
         },
       },
     },
  },
])
```

results which drop the extra key I wanted to keep:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : [ {
  "x" : 2, "y" : 1, "magnitude" : 2.23606797749979 }, {
  "x" : 0, "y" : 1, "magnitude" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "a" : [ { "x" : 2, "y" : 5, "magnitude" : 5.385164807134504 } ] }
```

The only other way I could think of is chaining `$unwind`, `$addFields`, and `$group`. But to prevent `$unwind` from removing document 1, I’d have to add a dummy entry to the end of each `a` array and then discard it when grouping them together again.

Is there something like `$map` but that behaves like `$addFields` so that I can just add a property to the nested document? Do I really have to specify all possible keys of the subdocument just to use `$map`? If I do not know the keys in the nested subdocuments ahead of time, is my only choice really the `$unwind` with all the extra pomp and circumstance necessary to use it?

### Current Workaround

Here’s my `$unwind`…`$group` try. But, as you can see, I need a ton of stages that wouldn’t be necessary if I could just get `$addFields`-like behavior inside of `$map` or some expression operator which would merge objects together like JavaScript’s `Object.assign()`:

```
db.things.aggregate([
  { // Add dummy to preserve documents during imminent $unwind
    $addFields: {
      a: {
        $concatArrays: [ '$a', [ null, ], ],
      },
    },
  },
  { $unwind: '$a', },
  { // Do actual calculation on single array element
    $addFields: {
      'a.magnitude': {
        $sqrt: {
          $add: [
            { $pow: ['$a.x', 2] },
            { $pow: ['$a.y', 2] },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      a: { $push: '$a', },
      item: { $first: '$$ROOT', },
    },
  },
  { // Remove dummy element
    $addFields: {
      'item.a': {
        $slice: [ '$a', { $add: [ { $size: '$a', }, -1] } ],
      },
    },
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$item', }, },
])
```

results which properly preserve any unanticipated keys in the original data:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "a" : [ {
  "x" : 2, "y" : 5, "abitraryPropertyWhichShouldBeKept" : true,
  "magnitude" : 5.385164807134504 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : [ {
  "x" : 2, "y" : 1, "magnitude" : 2.23606797749979 }, {
  "x" : 0, "y" : 1, "magnitude" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : [ ] }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`mergeObjects`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24879) aggregation operator is available in the 3.5.6  development release which will be rolled into upcoming 3.6 release.

```
db.things.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "a": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$a",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$item",
              {
                "magnitude": {
                  "$sqrt": {
                    "$add": [
                      {
                        "$pow": [
                          "$$item.x",
                          2
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$pow": [
                          "$$item.y",
                          2
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Using 3.4.4 & higher production release.

Use [`$arrayToObject`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23310) and [`$objectToArray`](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18794) in a `$map` to keep the existing key value and `$concatArrays` to merge the computed key value array.

```
db.things.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "a": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$a",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                {
                  "$objectToArray": "$$item"
                },
                [
                  {
                    "k": "magnitude",
                    "v": {
                      "$sqrt": {
                        "$add": [
                          {
                            "$pow": [
                              "$$item.x",
                              2
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "$pow": [
                              "$$item.y",
                              2
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Oh, and I had just finished [writing a question asking if such a thing existed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45000574/how-can-i-merge-two-objects-like-object-assign-in-an-aggregation-pipeline). Hrm, now, I wonder if I can get this build running in the environments I need it in…

Comment: I have added a version that you can use with current production release 3.4.4 and higher.

Comment: Can’t wait for 3.6, but that 3.4.4-compatible workaround is still a ton better than anything I could think of. Seems like [it isn’t documented yet](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10459), so this is very helpful!